# Select Number of Terms from a LARGE list given Probability in Python

Tags: python, numpy

I need to select a number of terms from a larger list in Python with each term having a particular probability. The following code works when the number of terms is about 10K.

```
import numpy as np

selected_terms = np.random.choice(terms, num_select, replace=False, probability)
```

I need to select from a list of terms over 20M (which may increase to 30M over time). 
I get: Memory Error
I have a machine with 64GB ram. It fails when I truncate the term list to even 100K.
I don't know precisely what np.random.choice does under the hood to produce results so I don't even know how big this gets in memory.

To give you some background on the data:
terms: list of strings [s0, s1, s2, ...]
num_select: number of terms I want to select (about 400 for now but it may rise slightly)
probability: probability of occurrence of every element of terms [p0, p1, p2, ...] Each p is a float and they have been normalized to sum to 1.

I started with a list of tuples [[term, count], ...]
Each term has an associated count of occurrences. I split these into parallel lists and generated each probability by: count/sum_all_counts.

Is there another way to get the selected_terms that I need? 
Or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: What is num_select in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to construct a data frame **df** with columns **string** and **probabilities**. Then use the function from pandas as

```
pd.df['string'].sample(n,weights='probabilities')
```

where n is the number of strings you want to draw.

I hope it helps.

Comment: Great answer ... but I suspect he will have the same issue still using 32 bit python

Comment: Do you know pandas.DataFrame.sample normalizes the weights?

Comment: Hey, it normalises if the passes weights do not sum up to one. But in your case as you have calculated probabilities which will eventually sum up to one , you can pass them and they won't be normalised further.

Answer (score 1):

use 64 bit python the memory is limited by the processor type ,32bit python is limited to 2gigs per process ... then to complicate it further ... numpy requires contiguous arrays ... so you cant fit much in that 2G

Answer (score 0):

I used Python3 with Pandas. Fast.

Just cleaning up Bhargava's answer from above:

```
selected_terms = df['string'].sample(n,weights=df['probabilities'])
```

I also noticed that pandas.sample will normalize the probabilities for you. So I changed to the following:

```
selected_terms = df['string'].sample(n,weights=df['count'])
```

df:

```
string  count
------  ------
str1    count_of_each_string
str2    ...
...     ...
```

Does anyone know how pandas.sample normalizes the weights:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sample.html

Does it just do something like [count1/sum_counts, count2/sum_counts, ...] ?
Or does it do something such as Softmax? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Softmax_function

Or other?